# How can I create a .apk in Jenkins with a specific flavour?

Tags: android, mobile, jenkins

I've an android project that has 2 flavours defined. How can I make a build via Jenkins with a specific flavour?
This are my flavours in the build.graddle:

```
 productFlavors{
flavour 1 {
    applicationId "app_id"
    resValue "string", "app_name", "Flavour 1 app name"
    .......
}

flavour 2 {
    applicationId "app_id2"
    resValue "string", "app_name", "Flavour 2 app name"
    .......

}
```

}

this is how I build it in jenkins:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe you could use something like: clean build assembleFlavor1Release

Comment: Hi  fractalwrench, it works, than you :) Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your task currently tells gradle to do a clean build of all release flavors:

```
clean build assembleRelease
```

You can change this to build only one flavor, using the code below. See the [Gradle User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Tasks) for more info.

```
clean build assembleFlavor1Release
```